# Best practices collecting and storing HTTP Request data on mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, rest, httprequest

I'm developing an Android/iOS app with the relative BackEnd developed in Java with Quarkus framework and mongoDB as database.
Specifically I am developing the backend using RESTful Web Services with JAX-RS

I would like to record all the interactions with the backend for example the following record in the mongoDB should be collected for a POST call:

i.e.:

**method**: "POST"
**path**: "/shop/getShopbyID"
**address**: "91.42.56.67"
**host**: "www.example.com"
**userAgent**: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36 Edg/95.0.1020.53"
**body**: "{"id":"613f27459d26bf2e7a9f0a1b"}"

I am not an expert, so I would like to have the best practices to collect these type of data.
Could you please give me some advices ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, but MongoDB as a document store could pretty easily handle the case you call out. I think your document probably ends up like...

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('1234567890'), // You always get a _id in a Mongo document
  method: "POST",
  path: "/shop/getShopbyID",
  address: "91.42.56.67",
  host: "www.example.com",
  userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36 Edg/95.0.1020.53",
  body: "{\"id\":\"613f27459d26bf2e7a9f0a1b\"}", // Things can get funky here, is your content-type _always_ JSON?
  createdAt: ISODate("2017-04-27T04:26:42.709Z") // You probably want a timestamp
}
```

You've got choices to make, though. Are you sure you want to store the body? Are you sure the body is always JSON? Even if this is true now, will it be "forever"?

If it is always JSON, never anything else. Nothing is stopping you from just storing it natively in the `body` as a straight up sub-document.

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('1234567890'), // You always get a _id in a Mongo document
  method: "POST",
  path: "/shop/getShopbyID",
  address: "91.42.56.67",
  host: "www.example.com",
  userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36 Edg/95.0.1020.53",
  body: {
    id: "613f27459d26bf2e7a9f0a1b"
  },
  createdAt: ISODate("2017-04-27T04:26:42.709Z") // You probably want a timestamp
}
```

I'm also not sure you are going to get the "path", "host", "userAgent", and especially "address" if you deploy into any network that puts proxies and the like in front of your application servers. If the proxies aren't passing this stuff along, what you end up getting is those things from the proxy, not from the actual clients. I guess that is a secondary topic.

The bottom line is MongoDB as a document datastore does great with unstructured data. Querying on the contents of the `body` gets a little tricky if the structure isn't consistent, but just storing the stuff? That is the easy part.